# Unity - communicating with clientside Javascript and ajax. How to pass data back to the webpage from unity?

Tags: javascript, c#, wordpress, unity-game-engine

What I am really asking is this; if there are dependencies which are impossible to compile into the unity build, is there a way of still calling them from within the unity and simply using the scripts loaded into the browser from the website and communicating with them?

Relevant documentation does not address this deeply:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html

I am creating a website wrapper for a unity application. The buttons for the experience are located within the website, as the buttons affect the rest of the site, not just the unity application.

When certain content is loaded in the unity game play however, the app needs to be able to affect the website. Is there a way to pass the data back to the website in a creative way? Currently, I am including all my javascript code for the website in the unity compile, and it is erroring out on:

```
gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "/Build/DomumProto16_Web.json", {
    onProgress: UnityProgress
});
```

Sending data to the gameplay from the website:

```
gameInstance.SendMessage('Manager','Filter', JSON.stringify(filterActive));
```

Need to call this function from the unity gameplay. However, ajax.ajax_url is undefined due to it being localized using wp_localize_script() on the backend.

```
function showStudentWork(studentIndex){
        
    //make sure to remove all the 
    var x = document.getElementById("studentWork");

    var studentID = studentWork[studentIndex];
    console.log(studentID);
    
    $.ajax({
        url: ajax.ajax_url,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            action: 'getStudentPost',
            currentStudent: studentID
        },
        success: function (data) {
            x.innerHTML = "";
            x.innerHTML = data;
            x.style.display = "grid";
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(`Error ${error}`);
        }
    });
    
    return false;

}
```

*What I am really asking is this; if there are dependencies which are impossible to compile into the unity build, is there a way of still calling them from within the unity and simply using the scripts loaded into the browser from the website and communicating with them?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are two methods. One is, in my opinion, easier, but it is deprecated and you should ~not~ use it. Options two is the 'corrrect' way, but it is kinda ugly imo.

### Option 1: Application.ExternalCall

[Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/Manual/UnityWebPlayerandbrowsercommunication.html)

This option allows you to call browser javascript directly, but Unity has deprecated support for it and is probably a bad idea for anything long term.

In a given browser with a Unity web player working, consider the following:
In browser source, define a javascript function

```
<other html>
<script>
function foo(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}
</script>
```

In Unity, whenever it is nessecary:

```
Application.ExternalCall( "foo", "The game says hello!" );
```

This allows Javascript to be called from Unity.
There is similar functionality for communication in the opposite direction.

### Option 2: jslibs

[Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html)

This is the unity-endorsed way of doing things. It involved packaging javascript libraries into your games.

First, create a javascript file that will be packaged with your game. Here is an example file:

```
// Unity syntactic sugar
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
    // Declare all your functions that can be called from c# here
    alert_user: function (msg) {
        window.alert(msg);
    },
    other_func: function () {
     // does something else
     // etc.
     // put as many functions as you'd like in here
    }
}
```

Place that file, with extension `.jslib` in your `Plugins` folder on your project.

Then, in your c# files, you need to:

```
// Declare a monobehavior, whatever
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    // IMPORTANT
    // You have to declare the javascript functions you'll be calling
    // as private external function in your c# file. Additionally,
    // They need a special function decorator [DllImport("__Internal")]
    // Example:
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void alert_user(string msg);

    // With that unpleasantness over with, you can now call the function
    void Start() {
        alert_user("Hello, I am a bad person and I deserve to write c#");
    }
}
```

Et viola. You can call other javascript from your c# javascript, and interact with the dom, but I will leave all those decisions up to you.

### The other direction

In both cases, communication in the opposite direction (browser saying something to Unity) is the same format.

In javascript, create a `UnityInstance` (the way of this is a little two long-winded to put into this answer, check either docs). Then, just `.sendMessage`.

e.g.:
c#

```
...
void DoSomething (string msg) {
    // this is a c# function that does something in the game
    // use your imagination
}
...
```

javascript:

```
let game = UnityLoader // Actually load the game here
game.SendMessage('TheNameOfMyGameObject', 'DoSomething', 'This is my message');
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. I am using this now. This works flawlessly, but it's deprecated. Is there a replacement?

Comment: @stackOverFlew I updated the answer with the current standard as well now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it can be done using `WWW` call function

This is not a proper code okay . This will be just an idea for you.

Send a variable to the PHP function like this

```
string url = "" // add your URL here;
WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
form.AddField("YourFunctionName", "SampleFunction");
WWW www = new WWW(url, form);
yield return www;
```

Now in your PHP do it something like this

```
function YourFunctionName()
{
  // your function code here
}
```

and now on

```
$YourFunctionName = $_POST["functionName"];
 switch ($functionName){
 case "SampleFunction":
    SampleFunction();
    break;
 }
```

So the idea here is still you will need a PHP and from that PHP call your ajax :)

Comment: Thank you, I know I can probably write a whole set of new code to do ajax from unity, but the wordpress variables are not accessible from unity... This would be the last resort.

Comment: but you can always pass those variable from js right so there's no actual problem on that . You just wanted to make it more clean . haha